# ' Tax Calculation Method Based On' - what is the preferred setting?

Tags: magento-1.9, price, tax, rounding

I have a store that is configured to store product prices as inclusive of tax. In the tax configuration, I have 'Tax Calculation Method Based On' set to Total.

On some orders that have discounts, I have noticed strange rounding issues. For example, an order that contains 3 lines, totalling £290, with a discount of £65, has one of the order lines with a line total of £55.01, instead of £55 (which is the correct product price) - making the order total £225.01, rather than £225.

What is the cause of the above, and can changing the 'Tax Calculation Method Based On' setting influence this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably related to the famous magento rounding bug.

As a solution you can copy `/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Store.php` file to `/app/code/local/Mage/Core/Model/Store.php` and modify the `roundPrice()` method to round with 4 digits:

```
public function roundPrice($price)
{
    return round($price, 4);
}
```

Comment: it seems crazy this bug exists, in latest 1.9 release?! I will look at implementing your suggested fix, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

## Info

Round price in Magento based on previous rounding operation delta.

> [app/code/core/Mage/Tax/Model/Sales/Total/Quote/Tax.php:1392](https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/1.9.3.7/app/code/core/Mage/Tax/Model/Sales/Total/Quote/Tax.php#L1392)
>   [app/code/core/Mage/Tax/Model/Sales/Total/Quote/Subtotal.php:719](https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/1.9.3.7/app/code/core/Mage/Tax/Model/Sales/Total/Quote/Subtotal.php#L719)

```
protected function _deltaRound($price, $rate, $direction, $type = 'regular')
{
    if ($price) {
        $rate = (string)$rate;
        $type = $type . $direction;
        // initialize the delta to a small number to avoid non-deterministic behavior with rounding of 0.5
        $delta = isset($this->_roundingDeltas[$type][$rate]) ? $this->_roundingDeltas[$type][$rate] : 0.000001;
        $price += $delta;
        $this->_roundingDeltas[$type][$rate] = $price - $this->_calculator->round($price);
        $price = $this->_calculator->round($price);
    }
    return $price;
}
```

Sometimes this can cause an error due to the high delta calculation error (`$this->_calculator->round($price)`). For example, for this reason, some prices can vary in the range of **±1 cent**.

## Solution

To avoid this, you need to improve the accuracy of the delta calculation.

Change

```
$this->_roundingDeltas[$type][$rate] = $price - $this->_calculator->round($price);
```

to

```
$this->_roundingDeltas[$type][$rate] = $price - round($price, 4);
```

Changes need to be made in both files:

> [app/code/core/Mage/Tax/Model/Sales/Total/Quote/Tax.php:1392](https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/1.9.3.7/app/code/core/Mage/Tax/Model/Sales/Total/Quote/Tax.php#L1392)
>   [app/code/core/Mage/Tax/Model/Sales/Total/Quote/Subtotal.php:719](https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/1.9.3.7/app/code/core/Mage/Tax/Model/Sales/Total/Quote/Subtotal.php#L719)

**Don't modify or hack core files! Do a rewrite!**

The solution was tested on different versions of Magento 1.9.x, but maybe this will work in earlier versions.

## P.S.

Change `roundPrice` function, as shown below, can solve the rounding error problem, but it can cause others (for example, some platforms require rounding up to 2 decimal places).

> [app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Store.php:995](https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/bea006a3fe4c87dc87a262e379ba879c7c4f8805/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Store.php#L995)

```
public function roundPrice($price)
{
    return round($price, 4);
}
```

## P.P.S.

This answer is a duplicate. I am adding here answer because I do not have enough reputation to mark this question as a duplicate.